# synchronizing Javascript function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I am trying to include Dailymotion in my web app. I have one javascript file (for Dailymotion) and an inline javascript.I am trying to get the recomemmended videos from DM, for which I have a function ready.

Dailymotion.js looks something like this

```
login();
function login(){
  getScreenname();
}
function getScreename(){
  // print some name
}
function getRecoVideos(callback){
  callback(result);
}
```

## Inline.js

```
getRecoVideos(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

In the `inline.js` file, the call to `getRecoVideos` doesn't work because, the login is not finished. How can I synchronize the calls?

Comment: How is the login finish signaled?

Comment: add a call back function to login and pass the getRecoVideos as a finish function m8

Comment: Can you please show an example?

Comment: check out deferred promises: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/, or amplify publish/subscribe http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/

Answer (score 1):

Per [this documentation](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/sdk-javascript.html#sdk-javascript-method-login) DM takes a response function that you can use to then call the `getRecoVideos()` function.

**UPDATE:**

To make it so you can receive the event from anywhere you could do the following:

```
DM.login(function() {
    $(document).trigger("dm-logged-in");
});
```

And then to receive the event:

```
$(document).on("dm-logged-in", function() {
    // Do what you want here...
});
```

This is using jQuery. If you don't use jQuery see this for more data on how to dispatch events in Java Script: [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have managed to get the recommended videos, but only if call the function from the same js file(Dailymotion.js). I want to call the function from a inline js. How can i signal if the login is complete using Javascript(not referring to the API docs)